# Map<String, Map<String, String>> may not contain values of type String

Tags: java, hashmap

I am not able get the code to go to `else` block. The code always goes inside `if` block. Is there a way to validate the value of a Map<String, Map<String,String>>.

I get compile warning `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` may not contain values of type `String`.
Could anyone please tell me how to validate this?

```
public class TestClass {

  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> val= new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

public void setData() {
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("10", "1000");
    map.put("11", "alphabet");
    map.put("12", "1002");
    map.put("13", "1003");

    val.put("1", map);
    val.put("2", map);
    val.put("3", map);
    val.put("4", map);
}

public void showData() {
    if (!this.val.containsValue("alphabet")) {
        System.out.println("inside if ");
    } else {
        System.out.println("else");
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    TestClass obj = new TestClass();
    obj.setData();
    obj.showData();
}
```

}

Comment: `this.val` is a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`, so a Map with the types Key=`String` and Values=`Map<String, String>`. So when you ask if one of your values is a String in `this.val.containsValue("alphabet")` it can only return false because none of your values are Strings, they are all Maps.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Is there a way to validate them? Or should I iterate them first and then validate? cos there will be extra code which is of no use other than for validation.

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by "validate them" because i have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can use stream and check each map inside it, not very efficient if called frequently though

Comment: I am just checking if the map contains the value "alphabet".

Comment: Yes, it's called frequently. And I don't want to iterate.

Comment: Maybe you want `this.map.containsValue("alphabet")` instead of `this.val.containsValue("alphabet")`

Comment: No, I cannot. This is just an example to add the values to the `Map` -> "val". I want to validate to "val".

Comment: Then maybe you want the check if the val map contains a map that contains  the value "alphabet".